# What is purpose of `dns.resolvePtr()` method?

Tags: node.js

What is the `dns.resolvePtr()` method is used for?

source: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolveptr_hostname_callback

It Node docs it says that it 'resolve pointer records (PTR records) for the hostname' but it doesn't work (always returns `undefined`)

I found some other source with some demo but that doesn't work either: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-dns-resolveptr-method/

As far as I know pointer records can resolved from IP address (reverse lookup);

So what is the of `dns.resolvePtr()` method in node?

```
dns.resolvePtr('google.com', function(err, rec){
    console.log( rec );                          // -> undefined             
});

dns.resolvePtr('geeksforgeeks.org', function(err, rec){
    console.log( rec );                          // -> undefined             
});
```

Comment: If it returns `undefined` it means the value you as asked it to resolve is not a `PTR` record (it probably is an `A` record).